# NSubstitute Async returns null despite defined return object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous

I have a unit test that should return the specified object but it is returning null.

The Data Provider to test:

```
public class PlanDataProvider : BaseDomainServiceProvider, IPlanDataProvider
{
    //CTOR
    public PlanDataProvider(IDataAccessTemplate template, IEntityStore entityStore) : base(template, entityStore)
    {
    }

    public async Task<DefaultActionPlan> GetDefaultActionPlan(string referenceListId)
    {
        var objectId = GetObjectId(referenceListId);

        var defaultActionPlan = await Template.InvokeAsync(context => Task.FromResult(EntityStore.GetEntityById<DefaultActionPlan, ObjectId>
            (
                context.ActivityContext as IDataAccessContext,
                typeof(DefaultActionPlan).FullName,
                objectId
            )));
    }
}
```

The Test:

```
public async Task GetPlan_BadPlanID()
{
   //Arrange
   string badPlanId = "57509afbc6b48d3f33b2dfcd";

   ...snip...

   DefaultActionPlan jj = new ObjectId(badPlanId);

   //create EntityStore object
   var dataxs = Substitute.For<IDataAccessContext>();
   var estore = Substitute.For<IEntityStore>();
   estore.GetEntityById<DefaultActionPlan, ObjectId>(
        dataxs, 
        typeof(DefaultActionPlan).FullName, 
        new ObjectId(badPlanId))
   .Returns(Task.FromResult(jj).Result);

   var dataAccessTemplate = Substitute.For<IDataAccessTemplate>();

   PlanDataProvider pdp = new PlanDataProvider(dataAccessTemplate, estore);

   //Act
   var t = await pdp.GetDefaultActionPlan(badPlanId);
   //Now this confuses me as the compiler thinks t is DefaultActionPlan NOT Task<DefaultActionPlan>???
}
```

Anyway t returns null eferytime and debugging the test t is null because the GetDefaultActionPlan is not returning jj but instead null??

What am I missing to have jj returned?

---

Edit:

Both Eris and Gabe rightly pointed out that my Mock of the IEntityStore was not sufficient as that value...even though it specifies a return will not get passed to the wrapping InvokeAsync thus I needed to Mock the InvokeAsync as well.

Gabe's answer was slightly off as passing Arg.Any does not satisfy the InvokeAsync needed parms. However I do not fault him for this as I spent an hours tracking the inheritance chain across multiple projects (this is a big company). Something he does not have access to do.

In the end here is the code that resulted in success:

```
var estore = Substitute.For<IEntityStore>();
var dataAccessTemplate = Substitute.For<IDataAccessTemplate>();
dataAccessTemplate.InvokeAsync(context => Task.FromResult(
      estore.GetEntityById<DefaultActionPlan>(
               dataxs, typeof(DefaultActionPlan).FullName, new ObjectId(badPlanId))))
.ReturnsForAnyArgs(jj);

var pdp = new PlanDataProvider(dataAccessTemplate, estore);
```

Comment: When you create the substitute for `IDataAccessTemplate` you never defined any of its methods. Is `await Template.InvokeAsync` calling an empty mock of `InvokeAsync` or actually calling the method with the arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I don't see this in your code, I will assume that GetDefaultActionPlan returns the defaultActionPlan variable, and that Template.InvokeAsync is referring to the IDataAccessTemplate passed in via the constructor.

It looks like you are missing a mock return value for Template.InvokeAsync, and since it is wrapping the other call its return value is the only one you care about:

```
var estore = Substitute.For<IEntityStore>();
var dataAccessTemplate = Substitute.For<IDataAccessTemplate>();
dataAccessTemplate.InvokeAsync(context => Task.FromResult(Arg.Any<DefaultActionPlan>)
    .ReturnsForAnyArgs(jj);

var pdp = new PlanDataProvider(dataAccessTemplate, estore);
```

Comment: I believe you have me on the right path but still trying to work out a few nuances to Mocking the InvokeAsync wrapper...seems it doesn't like contex => Task.FromResult....seems I need to pass a bit more.

Comment: Great!  I spent some time creating simple version of your code to see how to construct the InvokeAsync mock call and Arg.Any worked in my test.  Just so I understand, does estore.GetEntityById return something other than a DefaultActionPlan object?